# Is it normal for a machine to run poorly on a windows network?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-domain

I have an Core i3 at home running Windows 7 and it runs absolutely fine.  At work I'm running a core i5 running Windows XP, it's on a large windows domain and performance is *absolutely abysmal*, frequent pausing, slow start-up and shutdown and all-round performance generally disgraceful.

Is this related to running on a network? Is there some sort of heavy dependency on the network?  The network performance is generally bad which is why I'm wondering if they are related.

Comment: I might reword the question title if I were you...It sounds a lot like flame-bait

Comment: If it runs services that depends on the network (like login) then yes. If not, then definitely no.

Comment: It sounds like the network at your work needs to be improved.  You cannot compare the performance of a 10+ year old operating system to Windows 7.  If you were to migrate to Windows 7 it would improve the performance.  Even going from Vista to Windows 7 did wonders here at my work.

Comment: Startup and shutdown delays are usually due to roaming profiles. Windows XP is also not quite as optimised as 7 (although both are better than Vista)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no reason for that to "have to" be that way.

Sharing any web connections or even intra-network would always degrade the performance of the web connection(s), they might even have limitations so everyone gets some of the bandwidth without anyone getting all of it.

There can be programs, databases, and files, that feed off a centralised computer within the network, called up from the central computer and not existing permanent On each workstations that can kill performace , dragging them through a net connection each time they are needed, when they could exist locally.

There can be stock computers of a low grade , purchaced in quantity , running specific programs for the purpose of conformity and compatability, and it might be that 90% functionality through conformity is better than broken speed.

There can be an IT guy who is too busy playing WOW , and restricted by the policies of the company and thier choices of computers, upgrades, and network. Who couldnt manage and control all the computers if they wanted to, if it was anything like your home computer :-)

and 101 other factors.